# Using Area Solar Radiation tool for many rasters with different latitudes and Z values?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, spatial-analyst

I want to count direct radiation for all Europe. As the [Area Solar Radiation (ASR)](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//009z000000t5000000) tool allows to work only on small landscapes, I cut my raster-Europe into fragments with respect to latitude. So each piece of raster will be analyzed with a different values of Latitude and Z factor. Everything is working fine, but...

I have over 4000 these fragments of raster and doing it manually does not make sense...

So I used both batch mode and ModelBuilder, but in both cases, both Latitude and Z factor are set to default values​​, ie, for Lat=45 and for z = 1. If I use the ASR individually, these values ​​are automatically calculated.

What should I do to batch mode or ModelBuilder calculated the value of Latitude and z-factor for each piece raster automatically?

Answer (score 1):

This is maybe not exactly the answer that you are looking for, but we've done the work "[here](http://maps.elie.ucl.ac.be/lifewatch/geoviewer.php?tab=sun)" and the data for direct illumination will be available for download in February.

For your information, the best way to script it is using Python (for your first script, you can export from model builder). You can loop on your images and change the value of the latitude in the same loop (arcpy.[Describe](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//018v00000066000000) to get the extent and compute the average latitude). But the problem when you cut in a lot of pieces is that you will miss some obstacles for the sun (imagine you are just cut at the North of the Alps.

Comment: Thanks radouxju, especially for the last sentences. It good way of thinking, I cut my map for bigger pieces

Comment: it not so much the size of your pieces, but the fact that you need a "buffer" on the side of each piece. This will add some processing time because the overlapping areas are processed several times, but you can avoid artefacts.